# Date & time query question (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table that contain date and time field.

```
id|date|time
=========
1|01/01/2001|10:45
2|01/02/2002|11:45
3|01/03/2003|12:45
4|01/04/2004|12:55
```

I need to know the difference  between the `MAX(date)` and the `MIN(date)`

And the MAX(time) and the MIN(time)

Something like.... `MAX(date)-MIN(date)` ???.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to learn to highlight lines of code, SQL, XML or fixed width tables, and then use the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to format those nicely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is your friend.

To get the difference in number of days: `SELECT DATEDIFF(day, MIN(date), MAX(date)) FROM [table]` = 1186

To get the difference in number of hours: `SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(time), MAX(time)) FROM [table]` = 2

To get the difference in number of minutes: `SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(time), MAX(time)) FROM [table]` = 130

Comment: thank's for the help, if i have this format (max): 2010-03-18 10:44:00.000 and (min) 2010-01-13 03:23:00.000  -  how to see the difference between ?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to get what you are asking is ...

```
SELECT 
[DifferanceInMinutes] = DATEDIFF(mi,(SELECT MIN(YourDate) FROM MyTable),(SELECT MAX(YourDate) FROM MyTable))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: You don't need the subqueries - `SELECT DifferanceInMinutes = DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(YourDate), MAX(YourDate)) FROM MyTable;`

Comment: Hey, I said I really *simple* way! :)

Comment: My way is really simple!  Subqueries are more difficult to read IMO ;-)

Comment: Actually, Andy ... I agree. But when I first started at SQL it made more sense for me. 

I'm somewhat amazed at the number of DATEDIFF questions on Stack Overflow. Maybe they should teach it in School?